# Passing a COM visible struct as parameter

Tags: c#, c++, .net, struct, com

I have a C# COM DLL, that declares a struct with ComVisible=true attribute. The COM client is a native C++ code. Can I instantiate the struct in my COM client and pass it as parameter to one of the COM API?

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("xxx-xx-xx-xx-xxx")]
public struct TestInfo
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public string string1;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public string string2;

}

public interface ISomeInterface
{
    void CallCOMAPI(TestInfo test);
}

public class CoSomeInterface : ISomeInterface
{
    void CallCOMAPI(TestInfo test)
    {
      // test.string1 --- access it
    }
}
```

Now since this is declared as Comvisible, I do have the necessary definitions in the tlb header. So can I write something like this in my native C++ client

```
TestInfo *ptest = new TestInfo();
ptest->string1 = L"something";
ptest->string2 = L"something";
HRESULT hr = provider->CallCOMAPI(*ptest);
```

When I try to do this it always throws an invalid argument exception. Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: L"something" is not a BSTR, you have to use SysAllocString().  Structs are an interop problem, you should use IRecordInfo in your C++ code.  Problems that disappear when you simply make it an interface instead with two properties.  Now it is as easy, obvious and trouble-free like the other interfaces and classes you declared in your C# code.

Comment: Thanks Hans. Sorry about that L"" thingy. That's certainly not what I am doing, got it wrong while writing it out here. I will check on the IRecordInfo. Making it an interface is certainly an option. But I thought let me make it work with structs if possible.

Comment: COM component are create via CoCreateInstance(). Also make sure that the COM server is registered.

Comment: @Andro47 - If I were to use CoCreateInstance(), I will have to create an interface for this struct. It is as good as creating another interface and a coclass. that's what Hans suggested previously.